# PHP Warning: random characters log file windows

Tags: php, asp.net, windows, amazon-ec2, iis-8

I'm running IIS 8.0 and PHP 5.4 on windows 2012 in Amazon Web Services EC2

I've got this output in my php.log which is causing PHP-FASTCGI.EXE to crash every time

[29-Sep-2014 14:01:54 Australia/Sydney] PHP Warning:  ÀSÀSÜ6 in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\site\includes\confirmregisteruser.php on line 67

Then I get the standard error from IIS

HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.4\php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly

Most likely causes:
IIS received the request; however, an internal error occurred during the processing of the request. The root cause of this error depends on which module handles the request and what was happening in the worker process when this error occurred.
IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the Web site or application. This can occur if the NTFS permissions are set incorrectly.
IIS was not able to process configuration for the Web site or application.
The authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL.
The request is mapped to a managed handler but the .NET Extensibility Feature is not installed.

Things you can try:
Ensure that the NTFS permissions for the web.config file are correct and allow access to the Web server's machine account.
Check the event logs to see if any additional information was logged.
Verify the permissions for the DLL.
Install the .NET Extensibility feature if the request is mapped to a managed handler.
Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click here.

Detailed Error Information:
Module     FastCgiModule
Notification       ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler    PHP54_via_FastCGI
Error Code     0x000000ff
Requested URL      https://site.com:443/includes/confirmregisteruser.php
Physical Path      C:\inetpub\wwwroot\site\includes\confirmregisteruser.php
Logon Method       Anonymous
Logon User     Anonymous

Any hints or ideas on how I can debug this one further?

Event log says much the same thing, except with less detail. Can post if you want

Comment: What output do you get from PHP on command line if you run C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.4\php-cgi.exe

Comment: The other thing to try, is to enable output_errors in php.ini and change it so it returns 200 not 5xx on php error.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was actually an issue with our MSSQL database.

to be specific it had to do with replication between publisher and subscriber constraints, once that was resolved the errors and the odd warnings in php went away.

I hope this helps somebody in future - however far fetched it may seem :(